# Prism navigation GoBack() using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I have an issue with creating a GoBack button (that works as intented :) ).

I am using MVVM and I have one region called `ContentRegion`. My `MainWindow` shows the GoBack Button and the region, that's it. Let's say I have `ViewA` and `ViewB` only. My basic navigation from `ViewA` to `ViewB` works fine. In `MainWindow` I set the region to `ViewA` at startup and I have my `DelegateCommand` for the GoBack button and the `GoBack()` and `CanGoBack()` methods:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    _regionManager = regionManager;

    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(AddCorpActView));

    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoBack, CanGoBack);

}

private void GoBack()
{
    _regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"].NavigationService.Journal.GoBack();
}

private bool CanGoBack()
{
    return true;
}
```

In `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` I have added the property:

```
private IRegionNavigationService _navigationService;
```

and

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    _navigationService = navigationContext.NavigationService;
}
```

When I use the GoBack-button to go from `ViewB` to `ViewA` I get no error, but nothing happens either.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line, where you use *view discovery* to assign the initial view.

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(AddCorpActView))
```

View discovery and view injection cannot be used in combination with the journal, [see documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/region-navigation/navigation-journal.html).

> The navigation journal can only be used for region-based navigation operations that are coordinated by the region navigation service. If you use view discovery or view injection to implement navigation within a region, **the navigation journal will not be updated** during navigation and cannot be used to navigate forward or backward within that region.

Instead use the navigation service only. Replace setting the initial view by view discovery with a call to the navigation service, e.g.:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", ...)
```

You could also move setting initial views with the navigation service to your module definition.

Comment: Ok, when I change that line to _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA"), the page is blank. So using the _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion",typeof(ViewA)) was the only way I could get the App to show ViewA at start-up.

Comment: @martints Where do do you create your main view model? At that time, the region manager might not be fully set up and the region is not registered or available.

Comment: In my App I register all views, Then I set up the main window with the region "ContentRegion" and in the view model for this use RegisterViewWithRegion for ViewA - this is where you suggested RequestNavigate, which doesn't seem to work. So is the issue that the xaml file is run before the corresponding viewmodel? When ViewA is initialized and shown I can use the RequestNavigate without issues to go to ViewB.

Comment: You were right about the region manager not being set up before requesting navigation. In the MainWindow.xaml I gave the region an x:name and I changed the constructor for the MainWindow to include RegionManager.SetRegionManager(_contentRegion, regionManager); and regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA"); I removed all initialized navigations for MainWindowViewModel. This fixed the issue - thanks a lot for your help!